# Jinja: variable inside string inside if statement

Tags: python, configuration, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to create the following loop in jinja:

```
variable: >
[
    {% for replaceme in list %}
    {
        'name': "{{ "string-{{replaceme}}" if replaceme == 'somevalue' else "string-something-{{replaceme}}" }}",
        'sshKey': "{{ lookup(...) }}"
    }
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

but this doesn't work, any ideas? i tried different quotes, different combinations of curlies, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nested `{{..}}` are not allowed.

Try: `{{ "string-"+replaceme if replaceme == 'somevalue' else "string-something"+replaceme }}`

Comment: exactly what I needed. just combine the strings with +, so simple. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [string formatting operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html).

```
[
    {% for item in list %}
        {'name': {{ "s1-%s" % item }} },
    {% endfor %}
]
```